# Why is AVPlayerItem not firing its notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, swift3

I have tried all `AVPlayerItem` notification with no luck....
Nothing is happening when the notification should post.

I'm trying to download a video from a website in WKWebView

Here is my code it is in swift 3.0

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.downloadAudioVisualItem), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntry, object: nil)
}

func downloadAudioVisualItem() {
    print("Hello")
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(false)

    NotificationCenter.default().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you have written the `downloadAudioVisualItem`.

Comment: I have updated the description... But all this code is available in UIViewController where the WKWebView is available.

Comment: I have to see the function `downloadAudioVisualItem`. I believe there is something missing in the parameters.

Comment: It only prints hello for now i was testing.... It is between `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidDisappear()`

Comment: Put your notification observer in viewDidAppear and not in viewDidLoad. Try this if it makes any difference. Or otherwise you are not listening to correct notification.

Comment: @Raffi any solution for it please help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are calling postNotification before even adding the observer. I mean the observer should be called first, so that only It can start listening for the notification.

Try this in `App Delegate`

`import AVFoundation`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let MyGreatNotification = Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntry
        NotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.hello), name: MyGreatNotification, object: nil)
        return true
    }

    func hello()
    {
      // Put break point here
    }
```

And add posting notification code in your initial view controller like this.

`import AVFoundation`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let MyGreatNotification = Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntry
        NotificationCenter.default().post(name: MyGreatNotification, object: self)
    }
```

That's it try running your app, you can see that the app will break at the `function` named `hello` in `App Delegate`.

If you are still not sure. Do this, put this posting notification code in `App Delegate` and put adding observer code in initial view controller, add the selector and put a break point in there, try running the app. You can see that the app didn't break at the break point in the initial view controller.

Comment: I am not calling the posting notification, shouldn't `AVPlayer` post it automatically ?.... "if not, how would I get the `AVPlayerItem` from the `WKWebView` ?

Comment: ```AVPlayer``` should call it automatically. Check through the documentation noh, I think you are missing something. Did you add relevant keys in ```info.plist```.

Comment: I am unable to see any `info.plist` keys in the documentation can you help me out ?

Comment: Anyone know how the AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntry can be filled with some log events? And what are these keys in info.plist?